# How to end the infinite loop in the java script in browesr?

Tags: javascript

`

```
//→ Write a program using prompt function to take input of age as a value from the user and use alert to tell him if he can drive
let age = prompt("Please enter your age:");
  age = parseInt(age); // Convert the input to a number
  function check(age){
  if (age >= 16 && age>=0 && age<=90) {
    alert("You can drive!");
  } else {
    alert("Sorry, you canot drive or the number is not vaild");
  }
}
check(age);
let runagain=confirm("Do you want to continue?");
while(runagain==true)
{
    let b=prompt("Enter the age");
    b=parseInt(b);
    check(b);
}
```

I want to test a program to enter the age and check whether it is valid for driving or not.
First to ask the age and second after confirming also it was fine, but the problem came that the loop does not end.

I check the while condition but cannot get it.

Comment: You never reassign `runagain` therefore, once it's set to `true` it's always that value. Just assign it in the loop. Or built something else that would eventually stop.

Comment: Set `runagain` to `false`?

Comment: You need to re-confirm and set `runagain` in the while loop; otherwise it stays true.

Comment: There no language named `java script` there is `java` or `javascript`. there is no hypothetical "scripting" language based on the java language

Comment: I tired to make the confirm in the loop and also try to change true to false but the loop get overflow again.

Comment: Thank you I got the solution of this problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77426639/edit) your question to include your source code as a working [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which can be tested by others to provide an answer faster. [Please do not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the "runagain" variable outside the while loop as true;
and then inside the while loop you have to write this "confirm("Do you want to continue?") " and assign the returned value to "runagain".

Comment: I had tried to make the confirm in the loop but the loop get overflow again.

Comment: Thank you I got the solution of this problem.